# How to avoid constructor to be call twice when a page is define twice in a page

Tags: winrt-xaml

I am creating a winRt app. In which I am having a Home.xaml page which having a another page called Market.xaml. So for snapped mode the same code is repeated.

Now my itemListView (used for snapped) and itemGridView (for full view) both have this page (Market)

```
<views:Market x:Name="viewMarket"/>
```

And the constructor of this page is called twice which I not want.

So do I use some flag kind of thing or some better approach is there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, let's talk about this:

XAML is basically a varying syntax to C#. So, when XAML references a control like your views:Market with `<Views:Market />`, you are actually putting in something like `new Views.Market()` in both places. Basically, invoking the class twice. Should the constructor not fire twice, the time-space continuum would split in half. Dogs and cats living together, the whole 9 yards.

But, more fundamental here, what is the purpose of the constructor in C#, or in a XAML class? Is to do expensive things that you would not want to repeat? No. The reason for this is because the completion of the constructor is necessary before the UI thread is released and allowed to render the control. The resulting effect is a UI hang.

Moreover, the C# constructor is a synchronous method. It cannot properly invoke or hold asynchronous operations. This means long-running or expensive tasks that should be invoked immediately, should not be invoked in the constructor because it would also require them to be synchronous and UI-blocking. It is because of these last two points I suspect your constructor is being misused.

The solution is in the XAML framework. The XAML Page pipeline includes the constructor (since it is a C# class and they all have it) but it also includes a Loaded event. In many cases, the hard work necessary to fill page controls is in the Loaded handler. This allows the page to render properly, then starts the long-running action that will ultimately and asynchronously update control content.

In WinRT, the Page pipeline also includes an OnNavigatedTo() virtual method in the base that you can override to the same effect. In the override you can include the hard work of talking to a service, deserializing from a file, or whatever you need to make your UI work. Both the Loaded event and the override can be asynchronous, and neither prevent rendering by freezing the constructor.

But, there's another thing to consider since we're in C# and that the rather common pattern called singleton that allows for us to reference a type in two different contexts but without creating a brand new class. This is accomplished by making the class constructor private, but exposing a public property usually called Instance that returns a single, shared instances in some static place.

That might solve your problem already. Then again, none of that is probably what you need. Assuming you already know all that, the quick answer is you can't prevent a constructor because a constructor is necessary to create a new instantiation of any class, including a XAML view. Instead, whatever you are trying to prevent being double might need to be a combination of the discussions above. An offloaded method, and a static reference to prevent duplicate efforts.

Something like this:

```
public class Market : UserControl
{
    public Market()
    {
        Loaded += Market_Loaded;
    }

    static bool AlreadyLoaded = false;
    void Market_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AlreadyLoaded)
            return;
        AlreadyLoaded = true;
        // TODO: your work
    }
}
```

But that might not do it for you because the static variable is scoped too large. Instead, you can control if it does the big operation with a dependency property you add to your control. With a boolean dependency property set to false, the second control knows not to do something. With it set to true, the first knows to go ahead. And, so on. This prevents all future use of the view or user control in your app from thinking it should not run because of the static property in the above solution. Then again, that might be perfect.

Best of luck!